# add module to pythonpath - nothing works

Tags: python, linux, module

I don't have root access so I installed psycopg2 module to /opt (I have permission for that directory):

```
$python setup.py install --prefix=/opt
```

I've tried several methods:

```
#.bashrc        
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:/opt/lib/python2.4/site-packages/psycopg2/
export PATH
```

or

```
#.bash_profile  
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:/opt/lib/python2.4/site-packages/
export PATH
```

I also tried `sys.path.append('/opt/lib/python2.4/site-packages/psycopg2/')`

nothing works:

```
$python  
>>>import psycopg2
>>>no psycopg2 module
```

Neither `/opt/lib/python2.4/site-packages/psycopg2/` or `/opt/lib/python2.4/site-packages/` path works

Please help, thank you

Comment: The environmental variable is called [`PYTHONPATH`](http://docs.python.org/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH)

Comment: show `ls -l /opt/lib/python2.4/site-packages` and `ls -l /opt/lib/pyton2.4/site-packages/psycopg2`

Comment: The only variant you didn't try was `sys.path.append('/opt/lib/python2.4/site-packages/')` which likely would have worked.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try `$PYTHONPATH` instead of `$PATH` in your bash configuration file.
For more info look at the official documentation on [this](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html) topic.

Comment: `PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/opt/lib/python2.4/site-packages/  
  export PYTHONPATH` right?