# What is the expected directory structure for submodule stubs to be understood by mypy?

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy

I have a package backed by an `.so` file for which I have generated stubs using `stubgen`, I renamed the original `__init__.pyi` to `impl.pyi` and added a `py.typed` and `__init__.pyi`.

the resulting structure looks like

```
site-packages/
├── __init__.pyi
├── impl.pyi
├── impl.so
├── sub_impl
│   ├── __init__.pyi
│   └── something.pyi
└── py.typed
```

here

`impl.so` is a module with a `sub_impl` "submodule" with entries created via pybind11's `def_submodule`

in another directory I have a `test_import.py` and a `mypy.ini` with the absolute path

```
[mypy]
mypy_path=/something/site-packages/
[head]
```

As expected

```
import impl as foo
print(foo)
```

gives

```
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
```

also

```
from impl import SomeObject
print(SomeObject)
```

gives

```
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
```

but

```
import impl.sub_impl as foo
print(foo)
```

gives

```
test_import.py:1: error: Cannot find implementation or library stub for module named "impl.sub_impl"
test_import.py:1: note: See https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/running_mypy.html#missing-imports
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

all 3 cases run fine under the python interpreter.

Whats wrong with the directory structure and what does `mypy` need to detect the submodule?

Comment: As for "what's wrong": the stubs are for a *module* `impl` and a *package* `sub_impl`. Notably, there is no `impl/__init__.py` and corresponding `impl/sub_impl.pyi`. (On mobile right now so cannot check whether they would be enough.)

Comment: @MisterMiyagi The ".so" file is a module with submodules? How do we make `sub_impl` not be a package, and instead be a module?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Do we need a `impl/__init__.py` for the `impl.so` or is it sufficient to have a `__init__.pyi` co located with `impl.so`?

Answer (score 0):

The structure for stubs depends on the *runtime* appearance of the code, not its implementation:

- a module `foo` corresponds to a file:
  `foo.pyi`
- a package `foo` corresponds to a folder and file:
  `foo/__init__.pyi`
- a sub-module or sub-package is placed in its respective parent package.

This is the same structure as for regular Python code. Similarly, [`py.typed` must be placed in the top-level package](https://peps.python.org/pep-0561/#packaging-type-information) – no matter whether it is a stub or real package.

```
site-packages/
├── impl.so                # the implementation
└── impl/                  # the stubs for...
    ├── __init__.pyi       # import impl
    ├── sub_impl/
    │   ├── __init__.pyi   # import impl.sub_impl
    │   └── something.pyi  # import impl.sub_impl.something
    └── py.typed
```

Comment: Testing with mypy, I think we also need a (blank) `__init__.py` in `site_packages`? also not sure if `py.typed` needs to be moved to `site_packages`.

Comment: @Mikhail Unless by `site_packages` you mean a package that is itself literally called `site_packages`, we don't. `impl` is a package, `site_packages` is a folder in which packages are; since it's just a folder, it should have neither `__init__.py[i]` nor `py.typed`. If adding either changes things for you, then your import path is messed up (e.g. because `PYTHONPATH` points at a `site_packages`'s parent).

Comment: Interesting, I always saw PYTHONPATH pointing at the library's `site-packages` directory: for example in an unrelated question (https://stackoverflow.com/a/7731964/314290)